# Un-Googled Android Experience With CyanogenMod + Amazon App Store?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-5, amazon-appstore

I was going to buy the new Amazon Fire store as I completely live within the Amazon ecosystem;  I've purchased apps there, I'm mainly a reader and audiobook listener.

However, with my new AT&T Next plan, I'm getting pretty screwed.

I do not have a Google Account and do not want to create one and do not want to live in the Google ecosystem.  Yet, the Nexus 5 at $350 is very appealing.

I was wondering what issues I might face if I bought the Nexus 5, installed the latest CyanogenMod snapshot, and used the Amazon App store on that phone.  Never installing Google Apps.

Does CyanogenMod out of the box provide a complete "deGoogled" Android phone?

Comment: If you install the latest snapshot, you're likely to face many issues. Install a release candidate or stable build instead for everyday use.

Answer (score 1):

CyanogenMod, along with most<sup>1</sup> other custom ROMs, only include Android code with a few Google parts - all under-the-hood, of course. They do not include apps such as Play Store, Google Now, Gmail, etc. These apps are available as a separate package commonly referred to as *GApps*<sup>2</sup>.

So the answer is yes, you may achieve a "de-Googled" experience if you opt not to flash the GApps package.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are some instances that custom ROMs already integrate the Google Apps, but these are rare.

<sup>2</sup> Google Apps